# Is it possible to load SQLite db in to memory and execute query?

Tags: c++, sqlite, memory

I am programing under C++, windows,
I want to retrieve all content in SQLite DB,
so I make use of "select * from XXX",
The DB is about 4M,
However if the system restarted, the first time query will be really time consuming.
I want to load the db file into memory, and execute select * from XXX in memory.
Is it possible to do it?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Technically the database is loaded into memory when you open it. But you can have pure memory-based databases, too. In that case use `:memory:` as the path when opening the database.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could still do the following:

```
sqlite database < script
```

with script containing:

```
.output dump.sql
.dump
.output.stdout
```

then start an SQLite shell w/o any argument, and do `.read 'dump.sql'`